# OpenAM- Not able to delete entity provider

Tags: openam, opensso, federation

I loaded an idp metadata xml as an entity from the openam console. But after this, the list of entity providers in the Entity provider table became empty. I'm assuming it's because the xml I loaded is messed up. So I tried the ssoadm command delete-entity to delete this entity ID. But unfortunately, I'm getting this error:

```
 entity descriptor has invalid syntax
```

I looked up on google and found [this](https://lists.forgerock.org/pipermail/openam/2011-October/003670.html).

So I know it's called OpenAM - 792. I want to somehow delete this entity ID and retain the list of entity providers in the entity provider table under federation tab. It seems I have to do it from the OpenAM server. Could anyone help me out with that? I basically need the location from where I can delete the LDAP entry from the config store corresponding to the entity ID.

Thanks

Comment: As the bug report suggests it's already fix in 10.0.0EA ... are your really running an older version?

Comment: I am running an older version. Is there a way to get all the entity providers back on the entity providers table? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the entity descriptor entries via ldapsearch

```
ldapsearch -h OPENAM_CONFIG_STORE_HOST -p OPENAM_CONFIG_STORE_PORT -D ROOT_DN_FOR_OPENAM_CONFIG_STORE -j PATH_TO_PASSWORDFILE -b ou=services,ROOT_SUFFIX_OF_OPENAM_CONFIG_STORE sunserviceID=EntityDescriptor dn
```

This retrieves the dn, then just use ldapdelete or ldapmodfiy to remove the faulty entry.